# Deleting a cookie using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, server-side

If i set a cookie using the code

```
var a = 'jn=900; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 2013 02:47:11 UTC; path=/';

document.cookie = a;
```

Then it is sure that `document.cookie = 'jn=900; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 1999 02:47:11 UTC; path=/';` will delete the cookie.

Is it necessary to set all the properties used to set the cookie for deleting the cookie?

Ie. whether `document.cookie  = 'jn=900; expires=Fri, 27 Jul 1999 02:47:11 UTC;'` is enough for deleting the cookie shown above, or should I also specify the path as used to set the cookie?

Assume that the cookie is accessible in the page I'm deleting the cookie.

Also is it possible to delete a cookie set by PHP using Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good practice to set the path to avoid issues like cookies set by mistake on a different domain (`www.domain.com` instead of `domain.com`).

Regarding the second question, the answer is yes, you can use Javascript to access and delete cookies created by PHP if they are not marked as HttpOnly.

`The HttpOnly attribute directs browsers to use cookies via the HTTP protocol only. An HttpOnly cookie is not accessible via non-HTTP methods, such as calls via JavaScript (e.g., referencing "document.cookie"), and therefore cannot be stolen easily via cross-site scripting (a pervasive attack technique[27]). As shown in previous examples, both Facebook and Google use the HttpOnly attribute extensively.`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie